# Ansible - find and set permissions, including sticky bit

Tags: permissions, ansible

Using Ansible 2.1.4.0

Is it possible to set the `sticky bit` and folder permissions in 1 task?

Example;

```
# Shell is used over find module cause symlink breaks and performance

- name: Find directories in /tmp which are not valid
  shell: find
    /tmp/test -type d
    \( ! -user root -o ! -group root -o ! -perm 775 \)
  register: find1

- name: Set 775 for found directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: vagrant
    mode: 0775
    state: directory
  with_items: "{{ findPermission1.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"


- name: Find directories in /tmp which have no sticky bit
  shell: find
    /tmp/test -type d
    \! -perm /1000
  changed_when: false
  register: find2

- name: Set permissions for found directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: vagrant
    mode: g+s
    state: directory
    recurse: no #cause it already found recurse
  with_items: "{{ find.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"
```

Right now, I must have 2 different tasks to set the permissions. But they overwrite each other.

Goal: set the permission to 775 and g+s in one task.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found it, one can use the official [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html).

```yaml
- name: Set sticky bit + 775 for directory
  file:
    path: /tmp/test
    owner: root
    group: vagrant
    mode: u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx,g+t
    # mode: '01775' # also works
    # mode: ug=rwx,o=rx,g+s # also works
    state: directory
```

Comment: btw, it is possible group them:

`mode: ug=rwx,o=rx,g+s`

Comment: @Kevin C, sticky bit + 775 for directory can be set with a single statement: `02775`

Comment: BTW: The question asks about "sticky bit" but OP uses the symbol "s" which is not for "sticky bit" but for "set user or group ID on execution". "t" is for "sticky bit" according to [chmod(1) manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html). But the answer is quite similar, just use `mode: "01775" instead of "02775".

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to reflect the correct values.

Answer (score 6):

> Goal: set the permission to 775 and g+s in one task.

```
- name: Set permissions for found directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: vagrant
    mode: 02775
    state: directory
    recurse: no #cause it already found recurse
  with_items: ____
```

---

But I don't understand why you were checking for SUID (`-perm /1000`) and setting SGID (`g+s`) in the code. Neither I know what is the value of `find`, because you registered `find1` and `find2`, but not `find`.

I also don't see a need to specify conditions for find, because Ansible module is idempotent/declarative and you want all directories to have the same permissions, so you can rely on Ansible.